# Subir archivo desde Angular a Java REST

Tags: java, angular, rest

estoy intentando subir un ARCHIVO (imagen o pdf, no he puesto restricción aún) desde Angular. a un servicio REST construido en Java, y a java me llegan sus datos, el nombre original de la imagen, el tamaño de la imagen, pero el archivo no está subiendo..

En java, el objeto FormDataMultiPart, debería traer entre sus objetos el InputStream, con el archivo. Si llega el FormDataMultiPart, pero no trae dentro el InputStream, su tamaño sale de -1

Bueno, obviamente quiero recuperar el stream, para guardar dicho archivo en BD desde Java
¿alguna idea?

Éste es mi Component.ts

```
//INSERT JUICIO
        this.juicio.idStatus      = 1;
        this._ceJuicioService.insertJuicio(this.juicio).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.juicio = response;

          //subir imagen
          if(this.filesToUpload != undefined){
            this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(Global.url+"files/"+this.juicio.idJuicio, 
                                                [], 
                                                this.filesToUpload, 
                                                'uploadFile')
            .then((result:any) => {
              console.log("result");
              console.log(result);
              form.reset();
            });
          }

            this.formJuicioHabilitado = false;
            this.getComponentJuiciobyId(this.juicio.idJuicio);
            $('#juicioModal').modal('hide');
            $('#juicioGuardadoExitoso').modal('show');
          },
          error => {
            console.log(<any>error);
            console.log("No fué posible insertar el Juicio");
            $('#juicioModal').modal('hide');
          }
        );
```

Éste es mi UploadService:

```
makeFileRequest(url:string, params:Array<string>, files:Array<File>, name: string){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var formData:any = new FormData();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                formData.append(name, files[i], files[i].name);
            }

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xhr.readyState == 4){
                    if(xhr.status == 200){
                        console.log("status 200");
                        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        console.log("final final");
                    }else{
                        reject(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.send(formData);

        });
    }
```

java REST:

```
@POST
        @Path("{idJuicio}")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        public String[enter image description here][1] uploadFile(
                 FormDataMultiPart form,
                @FormDataParam("uploadFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                @PathParam("idJuicio") Integer idJuicio){
            System.out.println("idJuicio: "+idJuicio);
            System.out.println("form: "+form);
            System.out.println("fileDetail: "+fileDetail);

            if (form == null || fileDetail == null){
                System.out.println("Error 400");
                return Response.status(400).entity("Invalid form data").build().toString();
            }
            InputStream fileInput = null;
            try{
                FormDataBodyPart  formUpload = form.getField("uploadFile");
                ContentDisposition headerOfFile = formUpload.getContentDisposition();
                fileInput = formUpload.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

                byte[] targetArray = new byte[fileInput.available()];
                fileInput.read(targetArray);
                Juicio juicio = new Juicio();
                juicio.setIdJuicio(idJuicio);
                juicio.setDocumentacionFirmada(targetArray);
                idJuicio = JuiciosDaoImpl.updateFileJuicio(juicio);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return Response.status(200).entity(fileInput+"-"+idJuicio).build().toString();
        }
```